# Custom slicing in numpy arrays (get specific elements, then every n-th) possible?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm in need of a more customized way to extract given elements from a numpy array than the general indexing seems to allow me. In particular, I want to get a number of arbitrary, predefined elements, then every n-th, starting at a given point.

Say, e.g., I want the second (as in index number 2) and fourth element of an array, and then, every third element, beginning from the sixth one. So far, I'm doing:

```
 newArray = np.concatenate(myArray[(2, 4)], myArray[6::3])
```

Is there a more convenient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's effectively identical to what you're doing, but you might find it a bit more convenient to do:

```
new_array = my_array[np.r_[2, 4, 6:len(my_array):3]]
```

`np.r_` is basically concatenation + `arange`-like slicing.

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.r_[np.arange(5), np.arange(1, 4)]
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3])

In [3]: np.r_[1, 2, :5]
Out[3]: array([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [4]: np.r_[:5]
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The downside to this approach is that you're building up an (potentially very large) additional indexing array.  In either case, you're going to wind up creating a copy, but if `my_array` is very large, your original approach is more efficient.

`np.r_` is a bit unreadable (meant for interactive use), but it can be a very handy way of building up arbitrary indexing arrays.